# How to get a button text in a function - tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to get the specific button (that triggered the function) text in a function?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def clicked():
    message = Label(root,text=f"You clicked {help?} button.")
    message.pack()

button0= Button(root,text="Nice day for coding ain't it?",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=clicked)
button1= Button(root,text="What does evil Morty want?",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=clicked)
button2= Button(root,text="Microsoft Edge==Chrome downloader",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=clicked)
button3= Button(root,text="Only real programmers use Mac",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=clicked)
```

**EDIT: I think I have found an appropriate solution**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def clicked(text):
    print(text)
    

button0= Button(root,text="Suit up!",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=lambda: clicked(button0.cget('text')))
button1= Button(root,text="Java should hide from kotlin",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=lambda: clicked(button1.cget('text')))
button2= Button(root,text="Could it be more boring?",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=lambda: clicked(button2.cget('text')))
button3= Button(root,text="Bazinga",state=ACTIVE,padx=200,pady=5,command=lambda: clicked(button3.cget('text')))

button0.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making the command a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function with an argument that has a default value that's what you want passed to it. Below is an example of what I mean. The slightly tricky part is creating the `lambda` with an argument that is the widget it is with. In the code below, this is done by separating the `Button` creation from the configuring its `command` option, which is now done after they all exist.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def clicked(btn):
    btn_text = btn.cget('text')
    message = Label(root, text=f'You clicked button "{btn_text}".')
    message.pack()

buttons = [
    Button(root, text="Nice day for coding ain't it?", state=ACTIVE, padx=200, pady=5),
    Button(root, text="What does evil Morty want?", state=ACTIVE, padx=200, pady=5),
    Button(root, text="Microsoft Edge==Chrome downloader", state=ACTIVE, padx=200, pady=5),
    Button(root, text="Only real programmers use Mac", state=ACTIVE, padx=200, pady=5),
]

for button in buttons:
    button.config(command=lambda btn=button: clicked(btn))
    button.pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. It worked. Now I'll look where I should improve both scripts for my needs.

Comment: g_odim_3:  You're welcome. Best of luck with that. I strongly suggest you read and try to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggestions to make your code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Sir martineau can you look the solution I've found? I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, that looks like another way to use a `lambda` to pass the argument to the callback function (except you're not following the PEP 8 guidelines with respect to [maximum line length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)).

Comment: I understand. Honestly, I'm very messy. Need to change this.

Comment: One general observation about your approach (and my own to some degree) is the repetitious code involved as it's usually best to keep your code as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233055/discussion-between-g-odim-3-and-martineau).